# Most efficient way to look for these inconsistencies?

Tags: sqlite

The project consists of a single table – let's call it `Table` for simplicity – with three columns processed by a C program:

- `ID` is a unique ID and not really important here
- `Source` includes input texts.
- `Translation` includes modified/translated versions of the contents in `Source`.

Here's an example with made up contents:
[image: Example Table]

As you can see, the table follows a certain pattern and the goal is to find inconsistencies according to these rules:

- All IDs are unique and there's no association available connecting related entries with each other.
- Both `Source` and `Translation` contain a majority of entries that do not follow this pattern (omitted above).
- If there's a record A with `Source` set to `ABC` and a different record B with `Source` set to `Map: ABC` (it is identical to `Map:` followed by A's `Source`), then `Translation` of B must be identical to `Karte:` followed by `Translation` of A. Or in other words: the `Translation` column is supposed to follow the same pattern as `Source`.
- In the example table above, the result of the query should tell you that `ID_34567` and `ID_45678` mismatch, since `Translation` for the latter reads `Karte: Project B` rather than `Karte: Projekt B` (as dictated by `Translation` of `ID_34567`).
- The query (or queries) are supposed to be implemented in SQLite, hosted in C code (so it doesn't have to be 100% in SQLite only).
- Available SQLite commands are extended with custom functions for regular expression matching (PCRE2), for example `rxmatch(rx, text)` returns the portion of `text` matching the regular expression or `0` in case of no match. This list can be expanded or modified as needed.

So far the implementation first uses a query to identify all `Map:` entries:

```
select ID, rxmatch('(?<=Map: ).*', Source) as ms, rxmatch('(?<=: ).*', Translation) as mt from `Table` where ms != 0 and mt != 0;
```

A second query runs for every result row and checks for inconsistencies to return them (it selects concatenated fields from `a`/`b` but I'm omitting these for readability). The parameters used are the three columns returned above (id, matched source portion, matched target portion).

```
select ... as translation from `Table` as a inner join `Table` as b on a.ID = ? and b.Source = ? and not b.Translation = ?;
```

While this works perfectly fine, it's not the fastest query and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to simplify this and speed it up at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable AS A
JOIN MyTable AS B ON 'Map: '   || A.Source      =  B.Source
                 AND 'Karte: ' || A.Translation <> B.Translation;
```

This requires an index on `Source` to be efficient (or, even better, a [covering index](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) on both `Source` and `Translation`, if you have the disk space).

Comment: Ah, neat. Using string concatenation in the `on` condition was something so obvious I didn't think about. Giving it a spin later, thanks.